# How to configure Terraform provider with a Terraform generated file as a configuration value?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-helm

The Helm provider in principle can be configured as

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_path = local_sensitive_file.kubeconfig.filename
  }
}

resource "local_sensitive_file" "kubeconfig" {
    content_base64  = linode_lke_cluster.this.kubeconfig
    filename = "${path.module}/kubeconfig"
}
```

The above works for an empty state file, but `terraform plan` fails when the state file already exists.

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: stat ./kubeconfig: no such file or directory
```

The issue is that initially the file does not exist. It would be created by Terraform, once it reaches out to (in this case) `linode_lke_cluster.this` resource.

The [Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#provider-configuration-1) says that

> You can use expressions in the values of these configuration arguments, but can only reference values that are known before the configuration is applied. This means you can safely reference input variables, but not attributes exported by resources (with an exception for resource arguments that are specified directly in the configuration).

The filename needed for the provider is already known. Thus we are good with the docs. Still, as the file does not exist, the `terraform plan` command fails.

How can I work around this? Is this a bug that would need to be reported?

Comment: Have you tried using `depends_on` in the `provider` block? Not sure that would work, but worth a try.

Comment: @MarkoE I tried setting `depends_on` on the provider or the `helm_release`. Neither works.

Comment: Oh wait, have you tried just providing the same thing in `config_path`, i.e., `config_path = ${path.module}/kubeconfig`?

Comment: I've tried it. It's not the filepath, that's unknown, but the helm provider can not set up the connection to refresh the state, because the file is not populated yet. I even tried adding an empty file and set `depends_on` on the `helm_release`, but it did not help.